# Symfony - Always LOGGED OUT when i go to /login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony4

My problem is very simple and I am on this since this morning..

When I go to /login, i am directly disconnected, i switch to anonymous status on symfony 5.

This is my login controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
 * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
 * @return Response
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
     if ($this->getUser()) {
         return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
     }

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
}
```

Before I come in my condition (if.. this->getUser()), I am already disconnected.

This is my log out controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
 */
public function logout()
{
    // controller can be blank: it will never be executed!
    throw new \Exception('Don\'t forget to activate logout in security.yaml');
}
```

and the security.yaml :

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: users_in_memory
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\SecureAuthentication
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            target: index

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

thanks a lot and have a good day

Comment: Inside the login function, try `dd($this->getUser());` before the If condition and go to /login route and tell us what it prints?

Comment: hey thanks a lot : this is what it prints : SecurityController.php on line 18:
null

Answer (score 3):

In your main firewall configuration you have set

```yaml
    main:
        provider: users_in_memory
```

So you are using a provider with no users, therefore you should not be able to login. Try changing it to `app_user_provider`.

Also, you are missing a pattern on your main firewall. I've never had firewall configurations without pattern so I'm not sure what happens in that case. It is possible it just skips it.

```yaml
    main:
        pattern: ^/
```

You can try these 2 things, but be sure to do them one by one to know which one solved the problem (if this indeed turns out to be the solution) :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working, you're the best!!